# Reporting GLMMs

Tags: lme4-nlme, reporting

I have read several excellent resources (e.g., Bolker, 2009, Thiele, 2012)  on what should be reported, what is missing in the current research using Generalized linear mixed models, but I still have few questions...

I managed to fit a model using glmer (binomial family with logit link). Compared several different models, and choose the one that seems to be the best fit. The outcome variable is binary (0/1). Fixed effects are 5 continuous variables and 2 factors (graded/not_graded and yes/no). Students within a course was defined as a random effect.

The question is rather simple - what is the association between the five continuous variables and the outcome, and what is the effect of the two factors?

Are there any general guidelines what should be reported in the research paper in order to answer such a research question? I've seen a lot of statistics, graphs, everything... but I simply want to summarize a model in a table or two with a few simple graphs.

Comment: What do you mean by "association between" the variables? Are you asking how you should interpret the coefficient estimates in a random effect model?

Comment: I think I know how to interpret. I'd like to know if there is a standardized approach to report GLMMs in a research paper. For example, what would you report in a results section?